# Create issue: pushpin_attributes.viewer_state missing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

During creation issues on bim360 webpage pushpin_attributes.viewer_state object sometimes is filled and sometimes is not (depending on the published plan). 
In our case, the most important is pushpin_attributes.viewer_state.originalDocumentResolution (we use it to visualization issues in our custom applications).

Why can bim360 webpage on some plans figure out how to set pushpin originalDocumentResolution and on some plans can't?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that BIM360 can only extract this type of information from "richer" design files, for example from DWGs, and not from PDFs. If you could share one design file where the pushpins include the additional data, and one design file where they don't, please send them to *forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com*, and we'll investigate the issue further.